# Prove that subset $F$ of a metric space $X,D$ is closed if and only if $X-F$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Prove that subset $F$ of a metric space $(X,D)$ is closed if and only if $X-F$ is open

Proving if if $X-F$ is open then $F$ is closed is easy, I just need the definition of closed set.

for the other part, I know that for $a,b \in R$, set  $F=[a,b]$ is a closed set implies that $X-F=(-\infty, a) \bigcup (b, \infty)$ is open since $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty)$, so the union of 2 open sets is an open set. However, I'm not sure if this is enough, or I need a more general proof.

Comment: Did you mean to write $F$ instead of $D$?

Comment: oh, $(X,D)$ is the metric space, I forgot the parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose x is a point in X-F.  Then since F is closed and contains all its limit points, the point x is NOT a limit point of F.  By definition there is an open set O with x in O and O does does not contain any points of F.  That is, O is a subset of X-F.  This shows X-F is open as every point will have a neighborhood contained in X-F